# python call variables by str in the 'variable name list' (concat 100 dataframes)

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

```
#variables for df
a = pd.read_excel("/Downloads/1.xls")
b = pd.read_excel("/Downloads/2.xls")
c = pd.read_excel("/Downloads/3.xls")
d = pd.read_excel("/Downloads/4.xls")
e = pd.read_excel("/Downloads/5.xls")

#I want to concat them
pd.concat((a,b,c,d,e))
```

but the problems is that the varaiable name is too long and there are about 100 dataframe variables.
Hence I want to:

```
variables_list = ['a' ,'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
pd.concat(variables_list)
```

of course, it won't work. I just want to explain what I wanna do. Anyone has idea how to concat about 100 dataframe all at oonce in python?

Comment: Why aren't all the filenames in a list already? Then you could read them all into a list easily.

Comment: @DanielPryden Great!! listing filenames should be better! Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's `list` for it:

```
import pandas as pd

a = []
for i in range(download_num):
    a.append(pd.read_excel("/Downloads/{}.xls".format(i)))

concatenated_df = pd.concat(a)
```

If you have a **list of filenames** already:

```
import pandas as pd

a = []
for fn in filenames:
    a.append(pd.read_excel("/Downloads/" + fn))

concatenated_df = pd.concat(a)
```

Comment: Thanks!! python list can even store DataFrame?! amazing!

Comment: @Roy Sure, my pleasure!

Comment: @Roy: A Python list can store any kind of object at all. You would probably find the classic [Facts and Myths About Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) enlightening.

Comment: @Geeocode Thanks for updating~ it totally works well!

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks for your reply and great link~!